# CODA format d365 fin and ops automate bank statement import

Tags: axapta

Currently in D365FO 10.0.36 there is OOB functionality to manually import the CODA bank statement(ER reporting) however we want to automate the process for multiple bank accounts per legal entity. Can experts suggest an approach

Comment: Is this programming related? What have you done so far? Show your code.